# Cannot understand XPath syntax used

Tags: xml, xpath

In our framework a syntax has been used for XPath , but somehow i cannot understand the syntax correctly . Following is the syntax:

```
1. findBy("//div[contains(text(),'" + config.getKey() + "')]/following::div//select");

2. findBy("(//label[contains(., '" + config.getKey() + "')]/following-sibling::div//select)[1]"));

3. findBy("(//div[.='" + config.getKey() + "']/following::div//select)[1]"))
```

Now in point 1. what I don't understand is the use of single/double quote and also `config.getkey()` the method returns a String.

And in point 2. a `dot/comma` has been used in the beginning of syntax.

And in point 3. what does `.=` mean in the syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The double quote is part of the string concatenation that is building the XPath query. The single quote is part of the [contains](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains) function syntax.

2  The `.` refers to the [context item](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-dynamic-context) and  the comma is separating the parameters of the contains function.

3 The `.` is the context item being tested for equality.

It would make more sense if you substituted a plausible value for config.getKey(), did the concatenation and looked at the resulting XPath